# BufferedReader.readline() blocks output

Tags: java

I created a console chatapplication, that waits for user input with bufferedreader.readline() and should print chat messages from the partner simultaneously. But after readline() was invoked, no output is possible.

Waiting for messages and Sending Messages is realized in different threads.

```
public class MsgReader implements Runnable {

private Socket connection;
private final Console con;

public MsgReader(Socket sock, Console con) {
    this.connection = sock;

    this.con = con;
    this.run();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        System.out.println("asdf");
        while (true) {

            String ss = in.readLine();
            // System.out.println((char)in.read());
            // System.out.println("asdf");
            //
            con.write(ss);
            // con.write(ss);

            Thread.sleep(500);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}





public class MsgWriter implements Runnable {

private Socket connection;
private final Console con;

public MsgWriter(Socket sock, Console con) {
    this.connection = sock;
    this.con = con;

    this.run();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = connection.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    try {
        char in = ' ';
        boolean running = true;


        while (true) {
            String ss=In.inString2("");

            if(ss.equals("")){
                System.out.println("enter your message: ");
                //String s = con.readLine();

                String s=In.inString2("");

                bw.write(s+"\n");
                bw.flush();

                System.out.println("sent");


            }

            if(ss.equals("x")){
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);




        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("fail ");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

console

```
import inout.In;

public class Console {

    public Console() {

    }

    public synchronized void write(String txt) {
        System.out.println(txt);
    }

    public synchronized String readLine() {

        String temp=In.inString2("");

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your user input on a different thread than the GUI? Because it sounds like your GUI thread is blocking while waiting for user input

Comment: This is just a console application.

Comment: So you have one thread reading from `System.in` and one thread writing to `System.out`?

Comment: Excactly, to be more specific my messagewriter thread reads on System.in for an ENTER Key Press. Then it reads the actual message in a class with synchronized methods for printing and reading text.

Comment: `.readline()` blocks until input is received.

Comment: Ok, but how can I wait for the user pressing ENTER and print messages from the chatpartner at once?
it should be possible, because it's an example our prof from computer science class, gave us..

Comment: @user2147674 It doesn't look like you actually have multiple threads... And the only way you can get around the blocking behavior of `readLine()` is if it's on a different thread

Comment: i edited sourcecode, now it should be clear that there are two thread.

Comment: Perhaps it's the fact that your code is locking on your `Console` object, so you can either read a line from your `Console` object or write a line to it. Are you handling in/out through the `System.in` and `System.out` or through your own `Console` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `run()` doesn't start a new thread, it just executes the method.  You need to create a new `Thread`:

Runnable runnable = ...
   Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
   thread.start() // <-- actually causes the `run()` method to be executed asynchronously

Better still would be to use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

ExecutorService executor = ...
   executor.execute(runnable);

As these offer pooling of threads (amongst other features).